# What is right rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting, rule

I need a rewrite rule from this url (first) `?lang=rus&menu=about` to this (second) `/about_project/`.

I currently have this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about_project/$ index.php?lang=rus&menu=about [L]
```

But this redirects from second to first, I need a rule for first to second!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^[/]about_project/$ index.php?lang=rus&menu=about [L]
```

You should be looking for a / at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this tool:

http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

It's very useful.

Comment: it shows me RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^about_project$ /index.php?lang=rus&menu=about\  [L] it`s the same thing as my current rule